# Add Dynamic attribute with th:each in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to define a dynamic attribute, which changes it dynamically with the selected option.

*** Html/Thymeleaf code ***

```
<tr th:field="*{listArticles}">
  <td>
    <select class="custom-select" id="libelleArticle" name="libelleArticle">
      <option value=""> Selectionner un article </option>
      <option th:each="article : ${listArticles}" id="selectArt" 
              th:value="${article.libelleArticle}"
              th:text="${article.libelleArticle}"
              th:attr="att=${article.prixHT}" />                        
      </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prix" name="prix" 
            th:value="${priceArt}" th:text="${priceArt}" /> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

*** JQuery code ***

```
$("table #libelleArticle").change(function() { 
  var price = $("#selectArt").attr('att');
  $("#prix").val(price);
});
```

*** Spring Boot controller code ***

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newCommande", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {
  List<Article> listArticles = articleRepository.findAll();
  model.addAttribute("listArticles", listArticles);
  return "newCommande";
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? 
Anyways there is not property `priceArt` defined in your `Model`. Your `Model` has only `listArticles` property. So it will fail when you try to use this `th:value="${priceArt}"` and `th:text="${priceArt}"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But priceArt is defined. Just ,I forgot it when writing the code.. In other hand, The problem is resolved by use Ajax